# additing the same numbers in int and byte, why results are different? c#

Tags: c#, integer, byte, addition, operation

When it converts to int implicitly - the result is obvious, but when it adds bytes - it`s different, why?
[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code, not images of code.

Comment: what is the difference, if the question is clear?

Comment: Code in an image cannot be copied and pasted to reproduce an issue. Also, screenreaders can't read the contents for visually impaired people.

Comment: oh, ok, I just thought my code was too easy to copy)) but I got you

Comment: Yep, in this case it wasn't too bad (except for the folks who rely on a screen reader), but in general it's a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code just overflows `byte` — it supports integer values from 0 to 255. You should use at least `short`.